# Project fails to compile when automatically generating an adapter for a class that can contain instances of itself

Tags: kotlin, moshi

It doesn't look like I can add a field with the same type as the parent class if I want to automatically generate an adapter with moshi

Here is my code:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class CommentModel: ListingItem() {

    var id: String? = null
    var body: String = ""
    var created: String? = null
    var score: Int = 0

    .... // bunch of other fields

    // this is the cause of my compilation error
    var replies: List<CommentModel>? = null
}
```

The project fails to compile and gives me this message:

```
error:[ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
```

I checked the generated code and there isn't a circular dependency. If I remove the `replies` field, the project compiles successfully. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe file a bug report on the Moshi issue tracker with a minimum reproducible sample?

Comment: That was initially my plan, but I was hoping it was something obvious that I was missing because my lack of familiarity with moshi haha.